# List the memory and cpu of kubernetes nodes

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am trying to list the cpu and memory usage of all the nodes in kubernetes and echo "load exceed" if the memory or cpu limit exceed some digit. I am listing the cpu and memory this command but how to apply the logic to echo that `load exceeded`

`kubectl describe nodes | grep -A 3 "Resource .*Requests .*Limits"`

Output:

```
Resource                    Requests      Limits
  --------                    --------      ------
  cpu                         360m (18%)    13 (673%)
  memory                      2800Mi (84%)  9Gi (276%)
--
  Resource                    Requests          Limits
  --------                    --------          ------
  cpu                         1430m (74%)       22300m (1155%)
  memory                      2037758592 (58%)  15426805504 (441%)
--
  Resource                    Requests     Limits
  --------                    --------     ------
  cpu                         240m (12%)   5 (259%)
  memory                      692Mi (20%)  3Gi (92%)
--
  Resource                    Requests      Limits
  --------                    --------      ------
  cpu                         930m (48%)    3100m (160%)
  memory                      1971Mi (59%)  3412Mi (102%)
--
  Resource                    Requests     Limits
  --------                    --------     ------
  cpu                         270m (13%)   7 (362%)
  memory                      922Mi (27%)  4Gi (122%)
--
  Resource                    Requests      Limits
  --------                    --------      ------
  cpu                         530m (27%)    5 (259%)
  memory                      1360Mi (40%)  3Gi (92%)
--
  Resource                    Requests      Limits
  --------                    --------      ------
  cpu                         440m (22%)    5250m (272%)
  memory                      1020Mi (30%)  3884Mi (116%)
```

Comment: It would be great if you can add kubectl output sample as not everyone has a running k8s cluster to check how the output looks exactly.

Comment: Yes, add an input and desired out.

Comment: Hi I have added the output of the command

Comment: Can you describe your use case and what you mean by load exceeded? Because these metrics aren't reliable to determine how much resources you actually used. They only show reservation and overprovisioning of the resources.

Comment: When cpu request exceeds then the limit then it should say limit exceeded

Comment: I would advise you to read the documention about resources in kubernetes because i think you have a slight misconception in regards to their nature: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/

Comment: Is there any way to get all there in three different variable for each node? like memory in memory variable, cpu in cpu variable and request in request variable?

Comment: If you want to monitor your current resource consumption take a look at this page for first informations: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-usage-monitoring/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234682/discussion-between-bewu-and-user16133873).

Answer (score 5):

Try this to extract the attributes you want by matching a regex pattern

```sh
kubectl describe nodes | grep -E -A 3 "Resource|Requests|Limits"
```

You can extend it like this to extract `CPU` or `MEMORY` values

```
grep -E -A 3 "Resource|Requests|Limits" | awk '/cpu/{print $2}'
```

**EDIT**
To print if the limit is exceeded or not (example for cpu exceeding 1),

```
grep -E -A 3 "Limits" | awk '/cpu/{if($2 > 1) print "Limit Exceeded"; else print "Within Limits";}'
```

You will have to do

```
| awk '/memory/{print $2}' | awk -vFS="" '{print $1}'
```

to extract the number from memory before applying the condition as it gives the metric `G` with the number.

**EDIT 2**

This can give you the ratio based on the provided output of your grep command.

CPU

```
| awk '/cpu/{print $1,$2,$4}' | awk '{if($3 ~ /[0-9]$/) {print $1,$2/($3*1000)} else {print $1,$2/$3}}'
```

Output

```
cpu 0.0276923
cpu 0.0641256
cpu 0.048
cpu 0.3
cpu 0.0385714
cpu 0.106
cpu 0.0838095
```

MEMORY

```
| awk '/memory/{print $1,$2,$4}' | awk '{if($3 ~ /Gi$/) {print $1,$2/($3*1024)} else {print $1,$2/$3}}'
```

Output

```
memory 0.303819
memory 0.132092
memory 0.22526
memory 0.577667
memory 0.225098
memory 0.442708
memory 0.262616
```

Comment: Is there any way to check all of the memory, request and cpu all at once and check each one against there limit?

Comment: @user16133873 I have updated the answer. Please check if this works for you.

Comment: Any way to list CPU - request and limit? and Memory - request and limit?

Comment: I just calculated the ratio. Please check by removing the last `awk` section to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, depending on the resource type Kubernetes will behave differently and you can use kube-prometheus stack for CPU and memory exceed alerts.

- If you want to monitor your current resource consumption take a look
  at this [page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-usage-monitoring/).
- I'd like to make clear that your solution concept is unfortunately   flawed already because resource requests in kubernetes terms can by   nature never exceed [limits](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/node/resource-qos.md#requests-and-limits).
- The alternative is to use something like either the metrics server or
  prometheus e.g. in the form of the kube-prometheus-stack. With the   latter you can easily add rules that alert you whenever an app   exceeds the requests.
- The problem with limits is a little more    complicated because
  depending on the resource type kubernetes will    behave differently.
  If actual memory consumption exceeds the    configured limit
  kubernetes will automatically kill the corresponding    pod. On the
  other hand if actual cpu consumption exceeds the configured cpu
  limit it will lead to throttling which basically means    cpu time
  will be capped at the configured limit.